# Time required to do pipe output to head/tail

Tags: io-redirection, pipe, tail, wc, head

There are lots of txt files in a directory.

If I do `time wc -l *.txt | head` it takes

```
real    0m0.032s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.008s
```

If I do `time wc -l *.txt | tail` it takes

```
real    0m0.156s
user    0m0.076s
sys     0m0.088s
```

Does this mean that `wc` will know beforehand that it is piping to head and will only count for first 10 files and save time? In other words, is it aware of the pipe? And is this somethign special about `wc` or does it apply to all standard/built-in commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a `strace` on both commands. The interessting thing is that when you pipe the output to `head` there are only 123 system calls. On the other hand when pipeing to tail there are 245  system calls (or more when there are more *.txt files).

**Case: head**

Here are the last few lines when pipeing to `head`:

```
open("file12.txt", O_RDONLY)            = 3
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
read(3, "", 16384)                      = 0
write(1, "0 file12.txt\n", 13)          = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

When `wc` tries to write the output of the 12th file it gets an error `EPIPE`. Thats why `head` exited after getting the 11th line. When `head` exits, `wc` gets `SIGPIPE`. As seen in the strace output above, `wc` first tries to write to that pipe (where `head` no longer reads from) and gets an error that the pipe is broken.

> The SIGPIPE signal is sent to a process when it attempts to write to a
>   pipe without a process connected to the other end. -- from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal)

**Case: tail**

When pipeing to `tail`, there is nothing like that above. wc ends gracefully after writingall the output to the pipe where `tail` needs to be connected to for the whole time. `tail` needs all lines before it can print the last 10 of them. When there is no more output to read, `tail` prints the lines and exits gracefully too

Answer (score 2):

Any process that does not block `SIGPIPE` will be killed if its output goes to the write end of a pipe that no one is reading from.

So as soon as `head` closes its input (i.e. terminates), `wc` dies, which takes less time than finishing all the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for disappear your files:

```
time wc -l *.txt > tee   | tail
```

But a bit you add time for tee command to `time` .

With `tee command` :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen/test# time wc -l *.txt > tee   | tail 

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Without `tee command`:

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen/test# time wc -l *.txt | tail 
   8 f3.txt
   7 fi.txt
   5 mydata.txt
   4 newfile.txt
   4 t1.txt
   4 t2.txt
   5 test.txt
   4 text.txt
   0 t.txt
  49 total

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: I cannot understand this answer, what exactly do you want to say by including `tee` into the problem?

Comment: @jimmij it's exposing the thing I mentioned in my problem. Since tee needs to consume all of its output anyway for the copy it writes to the file, it is forced to block `SIGPIPE` and thus `wc` has to run for the whole time.

Comment: @o11c ok, I see.